# PyQt4 Toolbar Orientation

Tags: user-interface, pyqt4, python-3.4

I am trying to get a toolbar to run down the left hand side of my window, but so far it is horizontal. I have tried `setOrientation()` but I can't work out what arguments i need to put in it.

Here is my toolbar code:

```
self.toolbar=QtGui.QToolBar(self)

self.toolbar.addAction(QtGui.QIcon('new.png'),'New file', self.createNew)
self.toolbar.addAction(QtGui.QIcon('open.png'),'Open file', self.openFile)
self.toolbar.addAction(QtGui.QIcon('save.png'),'Save file', self.save)
self.toolbar.addAction(QtGui.QIcon('saveAs.png'),'Save file as', self.saveAs)

self.toolbar.addSeparator()

self.toolbar.addAction(QtGui.QIcon('about.png'),'About TextEdit', self.aboutMe)
self.toolbar.addAction(QtGui.QIcon('close.png'),'Close TextEdit', self.closeEvent)

self.toolbar.setFloatable(False)
self.toolbar.setOrientation(????????) # This is the line I'm struggling with
self.toolbar.resize(self.toolbar.sizeHint())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythons help function will tell you what arguments it takes:

```
>>> help(QToolBar.setOrientation)

setOrientation(...)
    QToolBar.setOrientation(Qt.Orientation)
```

So it takes a `Qt.Orientation` enum value as argument.

Enum values like these can usually be found as attributes of the the `QtCore.Qt` class, in this case the [defined values](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#Orientation-enum) are `Horizontal` and `Vertical`, so in your case, just use:

```
self.toolbar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
```